# Is there a keyboard shortcut for 'Insert table row above/below' on the ribbon in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to add a row to a table (created via *Format as Table*), but the only way I can see to do so is via Right clicking (or using the menu keyboard key).

Is there a keyboard shortcut similar to the ones that access the ribbon (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-><kbd>N</kbd>->...)?

Comment: `Ctrl` +`Shift` + `+` same time add row and `Ctrl` + `-` remove row

Answer (score 3):

To add a row you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> at the same time on the main keyboard or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> on numeric pad

And to remove a row <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> also at the same time

Comment: obviously a key combination is supposed to be pressed at the same time. And the shortcut is just `Ctrl`-`+`, it's just that the `+` symbol is pressed as `Shift`+`=` in the US keyboard, so when you press  `Ctrl`-`Shift`-`=` you get  `Ctrl`-`+`

Comment: This adds row above the selected row. What is the shortcut to add row below selected column?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an "insert table row below" shortcut by default, but you can create one:

1. Click the *Customize Quick Access Toolbar* icon at the top of the Excel window.

   [image: The "Customize Quick Access Toolbar" icon.]
2. Click *More Commands...*.

   [image: The "More Commands" menu item under "Customize Quick Access Toolbar"]
3. The *Excel Options* dialog opens to the *Quick Access Toolbar* page. Under *Choose commands from:*, select *All Commands*.

   [image: Selecting the "All Commands" combo box value]
4. Double-click *Insert Table Row Below*, then click *OK*.

   [image: The "Insert Table Row Below" command highlighted in the commands list box]
5. *Insert Table Row Below* should now show up in the Quick Access Toolbar at the top of your Excel window. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to see its shortcut number. In the screenshot, its number is 7, so its keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>. The number (and keyboard shortcut) will be different for you if there's a different number of commands on your quick access toolbar.

   [image: The "Insert Table Row Below" command icon on the Quick Access Toolbar, with its shortcut number displayed just below it]